# How to add two adjacent columns and then add the result to the next adjacent column cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data frame(in excel) in a single column and I wanted to add the two adjacent column then the result to the next adjacent column.

***Numbers:***

```
10
11
12
1
3
14
15
16
```

***Expected output (result):***

```
10
21
33
34
37
51
66
82
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `SUM()` function like this

```
=SUM($A$1:A1)
```

[image]